# Proving optimality for a new algorithm that finds spanning tree with contradiction

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, minimum-spanning-tree

Below is an algorithm that finds a spanning tree:

```
STNew(G, w)
   Z ← empty array
   for each edge e in E, taken in random order do
       Z ← Z ∪ e
       if Z has a cycle c then
           let e' be a maximum-weight edge on c
           Z ← Z − e'
   return (Z)
```

Does this algorithm always return a spanning tree?

---

I would say yes. It sort of looks like Kruskals algorithm in disguise - sort-of.

I am trying to prove this using contradiction. See below.

Assume that Z is not a spanning tree. That means there is a cycle or disconnection in the graph. There cannot be a cycle because of Line 4 of the algorithm.

But now, how can I prove that there isn't a disconnection?

Being fairly new to graph theory, I really don't have much of an idea other than that. Would someone have any ideas or advice?

Comment: Are we discussing directed or undirected graphs? The algorithm does  not work for directed graphs.

Comment: This would be for undirected graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the algorithm always finds a spanning tree (if such exist, i.e. the graph has a source). Not sure if it finds a *minimal* spanning tree though. You have already proven there are no cycles in the resulting graph, so we only need to show connectivity.

Proof that the resulting graph is connected:

Assume it is not, and there are (at least) 2 connected components U1,U2.

The original graph is connected, so there is some edge connecting `U1`, and `U2`, let it be `e`. Examine the point where `e` was chosen and added to `Z`. 

Now, since `U1`, and `U2` are not connected, there is some point that `e` was removed (otherwise they are connected). Let it be when we iterate some edge `e'`. The cycle involved contains `e` (because it is removed), thus it contains a node `u1` from `U1`, and a node `u2` from `U2`, such that `e=(u1,u2)`. W.L.O, let the cycle be `u1-v1-v2-...-vk-u2-u1`. But note that after removing `e`, there is still a path `u1-v1-v2-...-vk-u2` that connects `U1` and `U2`, so the components are still connected. This remains true for any future iteration, and it means the components `U1` and `U2` are connected in the resulting graph.

Contradiction.

QED

Comment: Thansk but Hmm, I find this proof a little hard to follow.

Comment: @britney It's a bit long because it is very simplified to minor steps. Read it through and let me know if you have a specific step you misunderstand.

Comment: One other thing: Should we prove that it contains all the vertices of G as well?

Comment: Is our assumption that U1 and U2 are not connected?

Comment: @britney The vertices are there, the tree we are creating has all the vertices by default, and the resulting edges set. The assumption U1 and U2 are not connected is derived from the fact that the graph itself is not connected, so there must be two unconnected components.

Comment: I think I understand your solution. One thing I get confused by is that you sometimes, switch from 'U' to 'v' to 'u'. Did you mix some of them up?

Comment: @britney No. I used U1, U2 as the components, u1 and u2 (lower cases) are vertices from these components, and v1,v2,..,vk as arbitrary vertices on some path I described.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I get it now. Now I am trying to find whether or not it finds the minimal spanning tree.

Comment: I don't see how "There was no cycle in the graph at this point" follows if the only restriction on e is that it links a vertex from U1 to a vertex from U2.  E.g. the original graph could have two different edges e and f satisfying this condition, and it could be that f has already been added to Z at the point when e is added, meaning that adding e *will* create a cycle (which will then, of course, be immediately removed -- but the point is that adding e will create a cycle).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Point taken, but honestly it does not matter to the proof. `e` is added to the set, and from then on (including in this same iteration), if it is taken out - the components are remaining connected.

Comment: Right, so can I suggest deleting that statement then?  As I've said, it's wrong, and as you have just shown, it's not relevant, so it's more than a bit confusing ;)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes of course, forgot to edit it earlier when I rushed out of home. Thanks for your review.